# Lost data in bigquery

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I made a Python 3 script to process some CSV files, but I have a problem with the data.

I send to the stream with the [insert_rows](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/cbigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html?highlight=insert_rows#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.insert_rows) function, if I only import  one file I have the same rows in the CSV and the BigQuery, but when I import more files, BigQuery lost rows respect CSV file, but insert_rows don't  return errors.

```
errors = connection.client.insert_rows(table_ref, info, selected_fields=schema)  # API request
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: I don't follow your question. Can you try and elaborate a little more?

Comment: Fix the problem add new unique colum into CSV

Comment: @GoldraK please consider to post an answer with the solution.

Comment: @MonicaPC I use this library for generate new colum and add in all row unique id

https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html

Comment: Great! Will be nice to add it as an answer to the question (not just in the comments) :)

Answer (score 0):

Issue was fixed by adding a new unique column into the CSV file, using [this Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html) to generate a new column and add in all rows an unique id.